# Easiest way from Undead Crypt to Majula (no bonfire)

Tags: dark-souls-2-sotfs

I'm doing no bonfire run. So far at the end of each long path, after each Great Soul I had a Primal Bonfire, which tp-ed me back to Majula. The next long path would Undead Crypt and, as far as I know, there is no primal bonfire there. What is the easiest path from Undead Crypt back to Majula or Drangleic Castle?

Also, when I went to shaded woods and wanted to go back to Majula I face a closed door, which wouldn't open even when I wait. How to open this door?
[image]

Comment: What about a homeward bone?

Comment: @GnomeSlice, are you suggesting going all the way from begging of the game to Undead Crypt without lighting a single bonfire, but the Majula one? >< This may work, but only in theory...

Comment: @klm123 For clarification, lighting a bonfire doesn't count against the achievement. If you're not doing a no death run at the same time, you could use bonfires as save points and strategically die.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's only one way back: the way you came from. Go back to the crypt's entrance, up the lift, back through the shrine of Amana, up the lift, back through Drangleic Castle, down the path to the Shrine of Winter, in the Shaded Woods fork area, then finally back to Majula.

After discussion with klm123, it appears the door in the middle of the building between Majula and Shaded woods takes about 10 minutes to shut back down. You can then pull the lever again and the door to Majula will open.

See this map for reference [image: DS2 map]

Comment: When you go from shaded woods to Majula you face the closed door, which wouldn't open. Have you actually tried this way, or this is just a theory?

Comment: You need to pull the lever again, only one of the 2 doors can be opened at a time.

Comment: what lever do you mean? I was able to find only 2 levers, both of them only Open Middle door. I can't pull them when the Middle door is already open. See the picture in the edited question.

Comment: ah, ok, i need to wait like 5 minutes, then the middle door would close and when i Open it it opens the door to the majula, nice.

Comment: Yeah I think it accounts for the time you'd need to kill the enemies the first time. It IS a trap after all.

Comment: actually it is 10 minutes... far far far more than needed to kill enemies in the trap exhausting... I went all the way to Drangleic castle doors and opened them, and when I went back I still needed to wait 3 minutes before that middle Majula door would close and I can come through. Stupid design, but at least, I'm not trapped like I thought initially.

Comment: That's weird, I don't remember it taking so long. Maybe there's some sort of trigger? I'll see if I can figure it out tonight.

Comment: @klm123 I went and tried the door both ways and it opens within about 30 seconds for me. Not sure why it took so long for you... Apparently this door serves as a loading screen between Majula and Shaded woods, maybe your PC has some issues? I was running on an SSD.

Comment: Funny. I don't think this is loading time, I can tp with bone and it loads in 3-10 seconds, All tp from any bonefire to any take the same time. But are you sure that we talk about the same thing? 10 minutes it is the time for Middle door to close after I open it with a lever, not to open. (and I need to wait until it closed because I can't use a lever and open the required side door otherwise).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60602/discussion-between-fhl-and-klm123).